# receiving data from a terminal by a mote with Contiki-OS

Tags: c, linux, contiki

I would like to know how to send data or commands from a terminal to a mote (TelosB or MicaZ) connected to the USB port of the PC.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Input-and-output)